# Solr 9.1 cannot make queries unless basic authentication is disabled

Tags: authentication, security, solr

I get this error:

`raise SolrError(error_message % (resp.status_code, solr_message)) pysolr.SolrError: Solr responded with an error (HTTP 401): [Reason: Error 401 require authentication]`

when basic authentication is enabled.
**Attempted option:** When basic authentication is disabled, the queries work.

Can any one point out where the problem could be?

Comment: The obvious question would be: are you sending authentication details when you have basic authentication enabled? How? Have you verified that you're sending the correct authentication details?